# Permanant Magnet Lines & Currents:

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

A permanent magnet produces lines of magnet flux that we call a "magnetic field".  Those lines come from inside the magnet, come out of the N pole, loop outside the magnet, & return back into the S pole to complete a magnetic circuit.  Using ferromagnetic materials, other magnets, &/or test equipment, we feel & measure forces that are caused by a magnet/s when other materials are placed within close enough proximity to the magnet/s (i.e. within their magnetic field/s).  We therefore conclude that the magnetic lines flow in a specific direction & exert definite forces (i.e. magnitudes/strength) on some materials (ferromagnetic & other magnets), depending on where those materials are placed within the magnetic field of a magnet/s.

We label those forces as "H Field" & "B Field".
We measure H in terms of Amperes/meter.
We measure B in terms of Newtons/meter/Ampere (or Tesla).
We also commonly defined B in terms of the force that it exerts on moving electric charges (i.e. the Lorentz force).

An "Ampere" is basic unit of electrical current in the SI system, which = 1 Coulomb per second--which is formally defined to be the constant current which if maintained in two straight parallel conductors of infinite length, of negligible circular cross section, and placed one meter apart in vacuum, would produce between these conductors a force equal to 2 × 10 −7 newton per meter of length.

A "Coulomb" is the standard unit of quantity of electricity in the SI system, which = the quantity of charge transferred across a conductor in which there is a constant current of 1 Ampere/Second.

Consequently, those "magnetic lines" are currents (or flows) of charges that don't appear to need any external source of energy to continue generating their currents.

We also know those magnetic lines exist inside a vacuum, so they are independent of air molecules to flow outside of a magnet.

**So now my questions:**

1. Exactly what charged particles are flowing outside (and inside) a permanent magnet that create the magnetic "lines"?
2. Do those particles come from something inside the magnet or does the magnet do something outside of it to affect unknown particles to make the lines?
3. If there is a current (i.e. a continuous flow of charged particles), then why don't we harness that current like a water wheel (instead of 'using energy' to rapidly move copper wires through magnetic fields--like we do with electricity generators?)  Shouldn't we be able to get the line currents to charge a capacitor (or or other device) & then later discharge the capacitor for the energy that we want?

Comment: But your main misconception seems to be that field lines indicate flow of particles. This is not correct. Electric field occurs around charged particles but it does not contain or consist of particles. Magnetic field similarly doesn't consist of moving particles. For that matter, no "magentic particle" (aka *magnetic monopole*) has ever been observed, and so magnetic fields typically have their origin from electric currents or ferromagnetic materials whose microscopic structure produces magnetic dipoles.

Comment: @The Photon - I posted it in the Physics SE & here also, because of my last question.

Comment: Yes, the field lines exist. No, it is not a current.

Comment: @The Photon - the magnetic lines exist. They are currents that have direction (i.e. they flow from the N pole to the S pole) & they have magnitude/strength. If the lines do not consist of charged particles, then what particles do they consist of in your best gu/es(s)timation? re: "...magnetic fields typically have their origin from electric currents or ferromagnetic materials whose microscopic structure produces magnetic dipoles." What particles does the magnetic energy that is flowing in a directional current outside of the magnet consist of?

Comment: @The Photon - How is it not a current if we measure the B field in Newtons/meter/Ampere (or Tesla) & H fields in  Amperes/meter?  Both Ampere & Coulomb refer to currents.

Comment: We measure forces in "kilogram meters per second per second" but that does not mean a force has mass.

Comment: Yes, a magnet has mass. But the magnetic field does not have mass. Nonetheless the units of magnetic field contains a mass term (inside the newtons) because the field produces an effect (a force) on things with mass.

Answer (score 3):

> Exactly what charged particles are flowing outside (and inside) a permanent magnet that create the magnetic "lines"?

The magnetic field of a permanent magnet is not caused by flowing particles.

The electrons within a ferromagnetic material, even if they aren't flowing, have quantum mechanical spin. If the spin vectors of many of the electrons within the material are aligned, they produce a net magnetic dipole moment, producing the macroscopic magnetic field lines associated with a permanent magnet.

(This is just another way of saying, even when electrons *aren't* moving, they produce a magnetic field. We don't really know "why" that is, but we have a mathematical model of how much field they produce and how it interacts with other objects, and we call that model the "spin" of the electron).

You can read more about this in the Wikipedia article on [Ferromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism#origin_of_magnetism).

> Do those particles come from something inside the magnet or does the magnet do something outside of it to affect unknown particles to make the lines?

It comes from the electrons in the magnetic material.

> If there is a current (i.e. a continuous flow of charged particles), then why don't we harness that current like a water wheel

Since the magnetic field doesn't derive from the flow of particles, we can't harvest it as if it were a flow of particles.

> We measure B in terms of Newtons/meter/Ampere ... Consequently, those "magnetic lines" are currents (or flows) of charges

The B-field has amperes in its units because it produces a force on a moving charge according to the Lorentz law:

$$\vec{F}=q\vec{v}\times{}\vec{B}$$

Since it is multiplied by a charge and a velocity to produce a force, it must have units $\dfrac{[\mathrm{N}][\mathrm{s}]}{[\mathrm{C}][\mathrm{m}]}$
in order for the equation to balance.

Just as a force itself has $[\mathrm{kg}]$ in its units because it has an effect on something with mass, although a force does not have mass itself; a B-field must have charge in its units because it effects charges, not because it is composed of charge or contains charge.

Comment: A permanent magnet has mass & it's magnetic lines create forces that cause those lines to complete a magnetic circuit & to affect ferromagnetic materials that are within its field. Clearly magnetic force is moving mass in that example. Based on the definitions of the B & H fields, I think we can reasonable conclude the lines are currents with 'something' flowing through the magnetic circuit--what is that something??

Comment: re:  "The B-field has amperes in its units because it produces a force on a moving charge according to the Lorentz law"-- or is it that a moving mass of charged particles (e.g. a copper wire) produces a force (Voltage) when it is moved repeatedly past a magnetic B field?

Comment: @zeffur, same thing. The force wouldn't exist if the B-field weren't there.

Comment: re: "If the spin vectors of many of the electrons within the material are aligned, they produce a net magnetic dipole moment, producing the macroscopic magnetic field lines associated with a permanent magnet."  The definition of a dipole is "a pair of electric point charges or magnetic poles of equal magnitude and opposite signs, separated by an *infinitesimal distance.*"  A strong permanent magnet has quite a lot larger dipole distance than the *dipole* definition shows.

Comment: Also, I still don't see how directional flux lines exist without energy or something flowing in a magnetic circuit.  Do we not have a word for whatever is flowing to create the magnetic field & directional current?

Comment: The spin of the electron has an effect similar to a displacement of two "charges", but no magnetic monopole has ever been observed. We only have this quantum behavior that has an effect like a dipole.

Comment: Electrical potential is the possibility (or potential) for something to have energy if it were placed in that location (but it isn't actually energy until the thing is put there). Similarly, a field is a mathematical model of the force that could be applied to something if it were put there. But until the thing is put in the field, no force is produced, and no particles are flowing.

Comment: Field lines are just a way of visualizing what direction the field points at each location in space. They aren't actual "things", and most physics and engineering analysis is done with no reference to "field lines".

Comment: If field lines are not actual things, then why does an iron filings  test on paper show automatically realign as the magnet beneath the paper is reoriented?

Comment: Also, regarding electron spin synchronization & the macro dipole of a permanent magnet--why is that dipole distance so much greater than atomic dipole fields?

Comment: iron filings are things. They are the kind of thing that if you put it in a magnetic field, it will experience a force (or at least a torque). This force (that is realized when the thing is put in the field) is what orients the things along the direction of the field.

Comment: In trying to better ascertain what a magnetic field really is & does, how would you describe the effects of rapidly moving (both pole faces) of a permanent magnet in a perpendicular direction to a 10" copper wire (which is not a ferromagnetic element) that has a multimeter connected to each end of the copper wire? And... what (if any) affects the copper has on the magnetic field. p.s.:  Why didn't these comments get migrate to the Physics SE when you migrated this question?

Comment: @zeffur You won't get any answers (at least the types you are looking for) to your questions because this is physics board. In order to answer your questions one must speculate which is beyond the purpose of giving accepted scientific answers to presented questions.

Comment: @Kimmo Rouvari Perhaps some scientist will reply with the latest theory?